# Modify size of the title on SelectItem component

Tags: smartgwt

Is it possible to modify the title size on SelectItem component?

I have:

```
SelectItem checkSelectItem = new SelectItem("name", "title: this is a test");
```

I would like that the title use only one line, but it use two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
checkSelectItem.setWrapTitle(false);
```

If you want to do the same thing for all the Items in a particular DynamicForm, you can also do the following:

```
dynamicForm.setWrapItemTitles(false);
```